# MediaWiki with BlueSpice is not showing content after sidebar adjustment

Tags: php, html, mediawiki, sidebar

I did some adjustments to the sidebar for instance added a link to a specific page. I was looking for guidance on this and found [BlueSpice manual](http://help.blue-spice.org/index.php/Navigation/de). They say you have to edit the site *MediaWiki:Sidebar*. Afterwards the link appeared in the sidebar. All fine.

But i noticed that the shiny icons disappeared. So i did some research on how to add an icon next to the link. The BlueSpice manual came up with

```
* recentchanges-url|recentchanges|Icon-letzte_Aenderungen.png
```

So i did this. Unfortunately i did not upload an icon via Special:Upload as recommende but named an icon form the skin folder. Thought this would work as well.

But since then i am not able to see any content in the wiki any more.
How could this happen and how can i revert this?
Since i am not able to login (because the content section stays empty) i cannot do changes to the page *MediaWiki:Sidebar* anymore.
I created a page via commandline with [sample Mediawiki:Sidebar](http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/MediaWiki%3aSidebar)and tried to overwrite changes via

```
php edit.php -s "Quick edit" -m oldSidebar < newSidebar
```

But this just creates another entry in MySQL and did no changes to the other one.
Maybe there is a way to upload the named icon somewhere? Or to revert changes? Or something else...

Thanks for help in advance!

Answer (score 0):

You may delete the Mediawiki:Sidebar page to restore back to the BlueSpice default sidebar.  From the command line:

```
php <wikipath>/maintenance/nukePage.php --delete "Mediawiki:Sidebar"
```